# Converting 0xFFFFFFFF to FFFFFF format

Tags: c, colors

I'm using byte shifting to get 0xFFFFFFFF color format in FFFFFF type. Colors that starting with 00 are being 4 characters in return.

```
printf("{%x}", 0x008000FF >>> 8); // returns {0080} which is NOT right, should return {008000}
printf("{%x}", 0xFF9900FF >>> 8); // returns {FF9900} which is right
```

Comment: Simply specify a "width" and "0 pad" in your format.  EX: `printf ("{%08x}",0x008000FF >> 8);`, or `printf ("0x%08x",0x008000FF >> 8);`.  Or, if you insist on 6 characters (instead 8): `printf ("{%06x}",0x008000FF >> 8);`

Comment: What is `>>>`?  Is that supposed to be a right shift `>>`?

Comment: `printf("{%x}", 0x008000FF >> 8);` does _not_ return "{0080}".  Instead it returns "{8000}".  (Assuming typo error `>>>` is meant to be `>>`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using `%06x` instead of `%x`. Since hex values are numbers you can use `%06x` like we do use `%02d` for 02, 05 or 09 .

Comment: I've made a Q & A topic.

Comment: Yes I'm. Try to ask a new question and you will see an option that says Answer your own question.

Comment: @Blubberguy22  Yes one can their own question. It is encouraged on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  You may want to earn the [Informed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed)